# IV regression computation

Tags: r, regression

For my thesis I am doing an Instrumental Variables (IV) regression and I was wondering if I did it the right way. Couple of issues I have:

1. Comparing the linear model with the IV models, the sign of the effect changes (positive to negative or the other way round).
2. Using Two Stage Least Squares (2SLS) with `ivreg` (from the `AER` package) gives negative R² values, so I decided to manually compute the 2SLS estimates. These give the same estimates as the `ivreg` code but now with statistically significant results.

I have limited data and therefore I did not expect any significant results as I already did some non-parametric tests and the means of the different groups were not significantly different.

I am researching the effect of policies of organizations on a given budget. 
The organization performs well if the budget residual is positive, so they have less costs than budgeted. 
The variable is a percentage, either positive or negative. 
There is non random selection into treatment as organizations can determine their own policy. 
Furthermore, the policy factors are mostly dummy variables, 19 variables are binary and 2 are categorical and 1 is ratio. 
My IV is any number between 0 and 1.

This is what I did:

#### 1. I estimate a simple Ordinary Least Squares model to see what it would do (I know the results don't mean anything).

```
lm1 <- lm(budget ~ policy1, data=df)
lm2 <- lm(budget ~ policy2, data=df)
summ(lm1)
summ(lm2)
```

#### 2. Then I performed an IV with the `ivreg` code, though the R² became negative which I thought was weird.

```
ivreg1 <- ivreg(budget ~ policy1| iv, data=df)
ivreg2 <- ivreg(budget ~ policy2 | iv, data=df)
library(stargazer)
stargazer(ivreg1, ivreg2, dep.var.labels=c("Budget"), covariate.labels = c("policy 1", "policy2") , align=TRUE, column.sep.width = "-15pt", font.size = "small", type="text")
```

#### 3. So I tried to do the 2SLS in steps myself.

Instead of `fitted.values(reg1)` I also used `predict(reg1)`. This gives the same output.

```
attach(df)
reg1<- lm(policy1~iv)
policy1.hat <- fitted.values(reg1)
reg2 <- lm(policy2~iv)
policy2.hat <- fitted.values(reg2)
ivreg3 <- lm(budget~policy1.hat)
ivreg4 <- lm(budget~policy2.hat)
stargazer(ivreg1, ivreg2, dep.var.labels=c("Budget"), covariate.labels = c("policy 1", "policy2"), align=TRUE, column.sep.width = "-15pt", font.size = "small", type="text")
detach(df)
```

With this step I got a positive adjusted R² but I noticed that the policy factors are now significant and that the sign compared to the `lm` model changes.

**Question:**
Am I computing the IV regression wrong?

Example data (not real numbers due to anonymity of data):

```
 df <- data.frame(
    budget = c(4,2.8,9.1,15.5,10.1,12.9,4.3,
               -1.9,-4.9,-1.3,14.1,8.6,7.8,-5.8,3.8,7.2,5.2,-5.3,8.6,
               3.5,-1.2,-15.7,1.6,6.9,12.6,10.4,4.5,-8.3,-15.3,
               9.8,21.5),
        iv = c(0.52,0.43,0.41,0.44,0.41,0.4,0.39,
               0.43,0.38,0.37,0.34,0.42,0.4,0.36,0.35,0.41,0.39,
               0.35,0.31,0.43,0.36,0.51,0.35,0.34,0.37,0.37,0.39,
               0.46,0.44,0.36,0.37),
   policy1 = c(1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,0L,1L,1L,1L,
               1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
               1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L),
   policy2 = c(1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,0L,0L,1L,
               0L,1L,0L,1L,1L,1L,1L,0L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
               0L,1L,1L,0L,1L,0L)
)
```

Comment: This question might be better suited for Cross Validated. If you don't get any answers, I'd recommend you ask there.

Comment: The fact that the direction of the effect changes is likely due to the data being very noisy. You're estimates come with a large error hence it can bounce around a bit (see also: http://personal.lse.ac.uk/YoungA/CWOI.pdf). The fact that your estimates are statistically significant when you do the 2SLS yourself is because the errors are incorrect. They are essentially too small. I think this also explains the fact that you have a positive R². For more help on  IV estimation see chapter 4 in Mostly Harmless Econometrics which serves as a useful introduction.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So, I dont have to estimate the IV myself but use the ivreg code? Do you have other tips how to improve my model? My data is very limited...

Comment: Also, the large error is in my own not as high as in the example I provided. The standard error is there 8.981. Is that still high?